# Efficient way of splitting large file into smaller ones based on column value

Tags: bash, awk

I have a very large csv file which I want to split into smaller files so that all the entries in the large file which have same value for the ID column (second column in the csv) end up in the same file. However, I also need to have 50 different IDs in each of the smaller file.

I have the code to do this, but for a 1 gig file, it takes around 15 - 20 mins. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

This is what I have right now:

```
awk -F, '{if(NR > 1) {print >> $2"_backfill_tmp.csv"; close($2"_backfill_tmp.csv")}}' $input_file
counter=0
for file in *"_backfill_tmp.csv"
do
  file_name=${input_file%.*}"_backfill2_part_"$PART_NUMBER".csv"
  cat "$file" >> "$file_name"
  rm "$file"
  (( counter++ ))
  if (( $counter % 50 == 0 )) ; then
    (( PART_NUMBER++ ))
  fi
done
```

The awk command writes each row into separate file based on value of column 2 (ignoring the first row which is a header), so that each of the rows with same ID value end up in the same file. I close the files every time because I run into a `Too many files open error` and I can't set the `ulimit` on the machine. However, this process only takes around 15 seconds, so it is not a concern.

I then loop through each of the temporarily created files, and write them into separate file till the `$counter` reaches 50 (i.e combine 50 file together). Now this is where it is taking a lot of time. I'm guessing since there are a lot of individual ID files, opening them one by one and merging them takes a long time.

I'm an awk beginner, so I'm pretty sure my code isn't efficient. Is there anyway I can do the whole process faster?

Comment: awk is **much** more efficient for bash than this, as it caches file descriptors. (Well, the GNU one does; other implementations can be much slower).

Comment: Not that you can't make bash that performs at least an order of magnitude faster than your current bash approach does (though it still will never be as fast as well-written awk) -- the trick is to stop using `>>"$file_name"` on every single line, and instead maintain a cache of open file descriptors. In bash 4.1, if you ran  `declare -A fds=( )` to create an associative array, opening a new FD and storing its FD number looks like `exec {fd_num}>"$file_name"`; and then `fds[$file_name]=$fd_num` -- of course, only running that code when you don't have a `file_name` entry in the `fds` array.

Comment: Similarly, when writing shell scripts where performance matters, don't use external commands like inside inner loops. Any invocation of `cat` or `rm` is `fork()`ing off a subprocess and `exec`ing an external-to-the-shell piece of software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Script For Unsorted Input

You can use the following script. I did not use `close` since now the number of open files is only #uniqueIDs / 50 instead of #uniqueIDs.

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 {
  if (!($2 in mapIdToPart)) {
    if (uniqueIds % 50 == 0) {
      maxPart++;
    }
    mapIdToPart[$2] = maxPart;
    uniqueIds++;
  }
  print >> "part"mapIdToPart[$2]".csv";
}' input.csv
```

This creates files `part#.csv` where `#` is the number of the current part. The input file doesn't have to be sorted. Rows with same IDs will go to the same part. The order of rows in each part corresponds to the order of rows in the input file. Each part has 50 (or less, for the last part) unique IDs.

## Script For Sorted Input

You can speed up the script when your input file is sorted by IDs, because then you don't need the mapping `mapIdToPart` and each generated part is written in one go.

The order can be alphabetical, numeric, ..., it doesn't matter. Here I assumed that the sorted file doesn't have a header anymore. If there is still a header, add `NR > 1` at the beginning of the `awk` script.

```
awk -F, '{
  if ($2 != lastId) {
    lastId = $2;
    if (uniqueIds % 50 == 0) {
      close("part"maxPart".csv");
      maxPart++;
    }
    uniqueIds++;
  }
  print >> "part"maxPart".csv";
}' sorted.csv
```

## Benchmark

To test the script, I generated sample data using

```
n=98""000""000; paste -d,
    <(shuf -i 10""000-99""000 -r -n "$n") \
    <(shuf -i 0-9""999 -r -n "$n") \
| cat <(echo data,id) - > input.csv
```

The sample data had two columns and 98 million rows with numbers in them. There where 10 thousand unique IDs. Meassured times where

- **3m 54s** to run the first script on the unsorted input.
- 1m 19s to sort the input using `tail -n +2 input.csv | LC_ALL=C sort -t, -k2 > sorted.csv`. The `tail` part removes the header.
- 1m 48s to run the second script on the sorted input.
- **3m 07s** For sorting and running the second script.

**Conclusion:** Even when your input is not sorted, it could be faster to sort and then run the second script.

Comment: Thanks! Sorting followed by aggregating works perfectly. But is there a way to name the part files as the input file name followed by the part number? I have the name of the input file in the regular bash script, and then I use it in awk by passing it as `-v op="$input"`. When I print it outside the awk command it looks fine. However, when I try to write the aggregated contents to the file in awk using `print >> $op"_part_"maxPart".csv";`, awk substitutes $op with the actual content of the file, instead of the name of the file. Why does that happen?

Comment: @drunkenfist use `op"_part_"maxPart".csv"` in `awk`. Regular variables in `awk` don't have a `$` in front of them. Please note that I made small change in the script. Yesterday I forgot to remove the header before sorting.

Comment: `print >> "part"maxPart".csv"` is undefined behavior, use `print >> ("part"maxPart".csv")` instead but of course you should really be using a variable for the output file name to guarantee the file you close() is the same as the one you were writing to.

Comment: @Socowi Yep, it works without the $. I thought I already tried that. And I already took care of ignoring the header row before sorting. Although I just used `(tail -n +2 $input_file | sort -t, -k2) > sorted.csv` What is the purpose of `LC_ALL=C` in your sort statement?

Comment: @drunkenfist tl;dr: it makes `sort` faster. --- `LC_ALL=...` changes the locale (here only for the `sort` command). `sort`'s sort order depends on the locale. Some symbols might sort in different orders for different languages. Respecting these orders is costly. `C` is the language of your computer, that is each character is sorted accordingly to its code point, often speeding up `sort`.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm always happy to learn new stuff. However, I couldn't find any literature supporting your claim. In fact, I can derive `Print >> "part" maxPart ".csv"` from the  `awk` grammar defined at [opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html): (see next comment).

Comment: `print_statement` → `simple_print_statement output_redirection` → `Print print_expr_list_opt output_redirection` → `Print output_redirection` → `Print APPEND expr` → `Print >> expr` → `Print >> non_unary_expr` → `Print >> non_unary_expr non_unary_expr` → `Print >> STRING non_unary_expr` → `Print >> STRING non_unary_expr non_unary_expr` → `Print >> STRING lvalue non_unary_expr` → `Print >> STRING lvalue STRING`  →→→ `Print >> "part" maxPart ".csv"`

Comment: A cursory glance at [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) doesn't reveal a statement on the issue wrt output redirection these days (it used to) but it is still discussed in relation to input redirection with getline in the RATIONALE section `...the meaning of these constructs has been made explicitly unspecified. (The effect is that a conforming application that runs into the problem must parenthesize to resolve the ambiguity.)`. To see the problem live and in person try running `awk 'BEGIN{print 1 > 2 3}'` on BSD awk in MacOS and you'll get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

you should sort the file for best performance

```
$ sort -t, -k2,2 file | awk '!($2 in a){c++; a[$1]; 
                                        if(c==50) {ix++; c=0}} 
                                       {print > "file_"(ix+1)}'
```

counts unique keys and increment the file counter after 50; print each line to the indexed file.

you may still need to close files if still above your systems threshold.